# Tengo un error con un elemento no existente en una pagina

Tags: javascript, php, funciones

Hola necesito buestra ayuda...
Estoy teniendo este error en mi proyecto

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "onclick", document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Me da este error por que en la pagina que estoy actualmente no existe ese elemento, si no en otra pagina pero comparten el mismo script para algunas de las funciones, creo que tendria que hacer una condicional condicionando ese elemnto a su existencia para decirle que si no esta en esta pagina que no lo ajecute pero nose muy bien cual seria la sintaxis

```
el elemento que me da error seria este...
document.getElementById('boton').onclick = function(){
 animar();
}
```

Comment: Hola hay un [post similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-can-i-check-if-an-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom) que podria ayudarte. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

La forma en que yo lo haría sería la siguiente:

```html
<button onclick="animar()">Click me!</button>

<script>

function animar() {
   //todo
   alert("funciona!!");
}

</script>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias

Comment: Si  mi respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor recuerda marcar el check como respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

No te recomendaría agregar el código `javaScript` en el html, es una mala practica. Mejor saca todo tu codigo `javaScript` a un fichero a parte y vincularlo al `HTML` con `<script src='tuScript.js' ></script>` justo antes de `</body>`

Para solucionar ese error simplemente almacena el botón en una variable y si dicha variable no es nula entonces agrégale la función.

```js
function loadEvents () {
  let boton = document.getElementById("boton");
  if(boton !== null) {
    boton.addEventListener("click", () => {alert("Me has pinchado")});
  }
  
  let botonInexistente = document.getElementById("botonInexistente");
  if(botonInexistente !== null) {
    botonInexistente.addEventListener("click", () => {alert("No existo")});
  }
}


// Esta linea para cargar los eventos una vez cargados los elementos del DOM
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadEvents);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='es'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" id="boton">Pulsame</button>
    <script src='tuScript.js' ></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: perfecto esto seria mejor idea,muchas gracias